# output plot from knitr custom engine chunk

Tags: r, ggplot2, latex, knitr

I've created a custom chunk engine for knitr with `knitr::knit_engines$set()` that takes some YAML specifications, interprets them, and creates a plot as output. If the knitr document is rendered to HTML I have it create shiny output which I convert to HTML with  `htmltools::knit_print.shiny.tag()` and that works fine. However, if I render to pdf/docx/odf I create a static plot object instead of a shiny output. That bit is fine, but all I can get it to render is a text representation of the plot (ie. a list object), rather than an image of the plot.

I need to somehow pass an image (I assume) to the output of knitr::knit_engines$set(), but if I try saving the plot to a png and then passing that as output, I just get the text representation of the file path instead.

```
knitr::knit_engines$set(example = function(options) {
  #### read options$code and do stuff - works fine
  p <- ggplot(data = mpg) + geom_jitter(aes(x = cty, y = hwy))

  ##### output results
  # Shiny - outputs html text. Works fine
  if(knitr::opts_knit$get("rmarkdown.pandoc.to") == "html"){
    shiny::plotOutput(p) %>%
      htmltools::knit_print.shiny.tag()

  # Static output formats (pdf, etc)
  } else {
    #### attempt 1 ####
    p # returns list object
  
    #### attempt 2 ####
    ggsave(filename = here("temp", "out.png"), plot = p)
    knitr::include_graphics(here("temp", "out.png")) # Returns here("temp", "out.png")
  }
})
```

I've looked through the [knitr/R/engine.R](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/3237add034368a3018ff26fa9f4d0ca89a4afd78/R/engine.R) on Github for inspiration, but have just gotten lost instead.

Comment: You should include a reproducible example, if possible.  It doesn't need to be your real code, just something short that behaves the same way, so we can try it and see if suggestions work.

Comment: Do you get the same outcome if you replace `p # returns list object` with `print(p) # returns list object`?

Comment: Unfortunately print(p) and plot(p) both return the same as just returning p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why this "fails" is that `knitr::include_graphics()` works this way: it returns a `structure` containing the path (and some additional arguments) which, in the case of PDF/LaTeX output, results in just the path being printed.

Instead, you need to pass the structure the output hook via `knitr::engine_output`:

```r
imgpath <- here("temp", "out.pdf")
ggsave(plot = p,
       filename = imgpath, 
       device = "pdf", 
       width = 15, height = 8, units = "cm")
knitr::engine_output(
      options, 
      out = list(knitr::include_graphics(imgpath))
      )
```

(Note that I save the image as PDF which I find easier to handle than raster images.)

````
```{example}
This is your example engine chunk.
```
````

[image]